# Ansible filter filename list with substring list

Tags: ansible

This seems simple enough but I can't find the ansible/jinja way to do it nor the correct keywords to find some pointers.

There's a list of file names (`firstlist`) (read from a file if it makes anything easier).
There's a second list (`secondlist`) with partial filenames to filter the first one. This second list can have elements that don't match.

`/tmp/filelist.txt` contents:

```
A-ok.txt
B-ok.txt
C-ok.txt
```

Tasks extract:

```yaml
- name: Read filelist
  command: cat /tmp/filelist.txt
  register: filelist_results

- name: "[FACT] filelist"
  set_fact:
    firstlist: "{{ filelist_results.stdout_lines }}"
    secondlist: ['A', 'C', 'D']

- name: "print it"
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ firstlist }}"   # <--- need to filter here?
```

Would result in looping just:

```
A-ok.txt
C-ok.txt
```

If `secondlist` contained the full filename, adding:

```
when: item in secondlist
```

would be enough.

It seems [`select()`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.9.x/templates/#select) is half the answer but I can't find the correct test to match the partial filename from the second list

Comment: Please do not edit questions with possible solutions. You are welcome to provide an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take your "filter" list (`["A", "C", "D"]`) and transform it to a regex of chars to look for (`"A|C|D"`) (using `regex_escape` on each list element for safety).
2. use the `select` filter to retain only element that pass the `match` test (i.e. the regex is found at the beginning of the expression)

In a nutshell, the following playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    filelist:
      - A-ok.txt
      - B-ok.txt
      - C-ok.txt

    keeplist:
      - A
      - C
      - D

    filteredlist: "{{ filelist | select('match', keeplist | map('regex_replace') | join('|')) }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: filteredlist
```

gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "filteredlist": [
        "A-ok.txt",
        "C-ok.txt"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Any way to escape the keeplist? It might not always be regexp-safe (example "test-database" outputs: `Error was a <class 're.error'>, original message: bad character range t-d at position 4"`

Comment: done in my edit

Comment: @Lennonry my initial solution was a bit buggy (wrong expression for the regex actually which was working with single chars). The latest edit will work for filter expression over 1 char and will escape each element in the list for regex safety.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Posting my final result in answer form as suggested.

After @Zeitounator this is where I ended up:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    filelist:
      - plugin-test-v1.txt
      - plugin-database.txt
      - C-ok.txt

    keeplist:
      - plugin-database
      - plugin-test
      - plugin-none

    regexp: "{{ keeplist | map('regex_escape') | join('|') }}"

    filteredlist: "{{ filelist | select('match', regexp) }}"

  tasks:
    - name: "print it"
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ filteredlist|default(filelist) }}"
```

Couple points:

- extracted the regexp in a separate variable because templating inline was giving me troubles with dash in the pattern
- the loop defaults to the full list if the filter ends up empty

Outputs:

```
PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************

TASK [print it] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=plugin-test-v1.txt) => {
    "msg": "plugin-test-v1.txt"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=plugin-database.txt) => {
    "msg": "plugin-database.txt"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```